# Predicting the Winner of a sequence of numbers

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, classification, sequence-analysis

I have various series of numbers of different lengths (ranging from 4 to 10) such as the example below:

[1.5, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 8.0]

[1.4, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0, 50.0, 100.0, 200.0]

For each one of them I know the number that won. Using the example above:

[1.5, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 8.0] ---> winner : 6.0

[1.4, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0, 50.0, 100.0, 200.0] ---> winner : 9.0

I have about 10,000 of them and I am trying to understand the underlying sequence / mathematical algorithm used to pick up the winner. The idea is that in the future if I pass in a new sequence I can either get most probable winner or a discrete distribution of the "winning chances" of each entry.

My initial approach was to try a few ML algorithms but due to the vast number of possible outcomes and the fact that some numbers are not always possible (i.e. if they don't exist in the input sequence) this is challenging.

Does anyone have any ideas for potential methodologies I could look into? I am currently using Python so if there are any packages that will help with this feel free to suggest them.

Comment: My first thought would be to consider the lists of numbers as a 1-dimensional array with 10 entries corresponding to the number of elements of that rank (allowing ties), and then have a response which is the rank of the winner in that list. So your first list would be [1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] and the response would be 3. This gives you 10 predictors (some of which will likely be near zero variance). From here I'd have to think more about what ML model I'd use

Comment: Thank you @ToddBurus that's a good idea, I will give it a try. An additional challenge I forgot to add is that it also appears to be an unbalanced problem. As around 40% of  the times the winner seems to be the first entry. I suppose I need to consider this when picking the right model.

Comment: Sounds good. I would probably consider tree-based models first.